# Redemption: RdoMail Delete flags

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-redemption

I am trying to delete a RdoMail using `dfHardDelete`flag. But in the documentation, it states that `Exchange Only. Permanently deletes the item; will not be recoverable` I just want to be sure what is the impact of using this flag if the RdoMail wasn't from Exchange ? Will it automatically switch to `dfSoftDelete` or will throw an exception ??

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely  dfHardDeleteflag will cause the "unknown flags" error.

Comment: Thank you Dmitry, I want to ask you. I need a temp message, so what will happen if I add an new message, and didn't save it ?? will it be deleted automatically, or should I delete it ?? what is the best practice ?

Comment: If you never called Save, it will never be saved.